# Background image on medium and lower screen makign white space horizontally bottom of img

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a background image problem with medium screen and lower... 
i tried background cover property but it adds horizontally white space bottom of image
how i fix that...?
the html is here
html

```
 <body class="bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    <body>
```

CSS

```
    .bg{
    background-image:url(http://themes.siiimple.com/360/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/FreeGreatPicture.com-18429-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover ;
    }
.box{
    height:400px;
    width:88%;
    background:#C5C0C1;
    opacity:.5;
    margin-top:50px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azhrhussain/1xtvvfL8/

Comment: try to set height of html and body, `body, html { height:100%;}` do you mean like this **http://jsfiddle.net/1xtvvfL8/1/** ?

Comment: see the affect @media 909x875 and bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the background-size property correctly, but your body element isn't reaching the bottom of the window.  Just add this to your html:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1xtvvfL8/4/

Comment: box works correctly... but the background not cover horizontally to the box... ?

Comment: I think I got what you need.  Take a look at my updated solution.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Don't forget to make this answer as accepted: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Please note that while background-size:cover works well in CSS3 compatibile browser it is known from having terrible performance. If you plan on using big background image across an entire site it is good to consider some JavaScript / jQuery solutions for both speed and compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid whitespace, add:

```
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

It'll remove any automatically-applied margins or padding by the browser to your page.

Comment: also not working... i tried but problem still remain... @media bellow 909x875